# How to see rosparam on terminal screen?

Tags: rosbag, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recorded all data in rosbag. When I play it using command `rosbag play <bag_name>`, I want to see ros_parameters of  amcl. When I type `rosparam list`, it does not list any amcl related parameters. In fact it  list only following parameters

1. /rosdistro
2. /roslaunch/uris/host_ubuntu
   3 /rosversion
   4  /run_id
   I want to get set and see amcl parameters. How to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280534/how-to-see-rosparam-on-terminal-screen?/) by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I play it using command `rosbag play <bag_name>`, I want to see ros_parameters of `amcl`

`rosbag` unfortunately does not store the parameters when you record a session, so there is no way to retrieve the parameters of `amcl` from your bag file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1